# Functional custom component in an object loop with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to display a list from a javascript object `props.fields`, which length or keys are unknown.

This works:

```js
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  title: string
  fields: Field
}

interface Field {
  [key: string]: string
}

const InfoPanel = (props: Props): JSX.Element => (
  {display(props)}
)

function display(props: Props): Array<JSX.Element> {
  const toDisplay = []
  Object.keys(props.fields).forEach((key: string) => {
    toDisplay.push(
      <div>
        <div className="info__line">{key}</div>
        <div className="info__line">{props.fields[key]}</div>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return toDisplay
}

export default InfoPanel
```

However when I try to factorize the `display` function with a subcomponent, it doesnt work anymore:

```js
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  title: string
  fields: Field
}

interface Field {
  [key: string]: string
}

const InfoPanel = (props: Props): JSX.Element => (
  {display(props)}
)

function display(props: Props): Array<JSX.Element> {
  const toDisplay = []
  Object.keys(props.fields).forEach((key: string) => {
    toDisplay.push(<Info key={key} value={props.fields[key]} />)
  })
  return toDisplay
}

const Info = (key: string, value: string): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    <div className="info__line">{key}</div>
    <div className="info__line">{value}</div>
  </div>
)

export default InfoPanel
```

My code editor returns an error:

```
Const Info: (key: string, value: string) => JSX.Element
Type '{ key: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Changing `const Info = (key: string, value: string): JSX.Element` to `const Info = (key: any, value: string): JSX.Element` seems to fix that error, but the component still doesn't render.

Why is this not working and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Info` is not a functional react component, functional components receive only one parameter which is the `props`

you can fix your code with two options

**option1** : use `Info` as function

```
function display(props: Props): Array<JSX.Element> {
  const toDisplay = []
  Object.keys(props.fields).forEach((key: string) => {
    toDisplay.push(Info(key,props.fields[key]))
  })
  return toDisplay
}
```

**option2** convert your `Info` to functional component

```
toDisplay.push(<Info title={key} value={props.fields[key]} />)

const Info = (props:any): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    <div className="info__line">{props.title}</div>
    <div className="info__line">{props.value}</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Note that `props.key` will return undefined. `key` is used by react for some other thing.